# cocoa NSPanel initWithCoder not being called from MainMenu.nib

Tags: cocoa

I have a top level NSPanel in my MainMenu.xib. I specified the class
of the panel to be my class which subclasses NSPanel. I was expecting the
method initWithCoder: to be called when the application launched but it
is not.

Does anyone know what I need to do get initWithCoder: called from MainMenu.xib
when the application launches? I'm new to Xcode and the UI of the xib file
in xcode is a bit overwhelming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-15207):

> Although the NSWindow class inherits the NSCoding protocol from
>   NSResponder, the class does not support coding.

Have you checked the other initializers?

- `-initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:`
- `-initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:screen:`

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: If this is the correct answer, then you should bestow upon it the Green Checkmark of Acceptance.